# Getting `Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'` error with `merge` in R

Tags: r

I want to join two tables on time. The input file has a column for hh:mm:ss and a column for am/pm. I seem to have successfully created a new column wih date information, but I can't join on it. The error message makes no sense to me and doesn't point to anything I gave it.

This:

```
t1 <- read.table("~/SEQ-1066/sar.r.54043.txt",header=TRUE)
t2 <- read.table("~/SEQ-1066/sar.q.54043.txt",header=TRUE)
t1$pt <- strptime(paste(t1$time, t1$AM),"%I:%M:%S %p")
t2$pt <- strptime(paste(t2$time, t2$AM),"%I:%M:%S %p")
t <- merge(x=t1,y=t2,by="pt")
```

results in:

```
> t1 <- read.table("~/SEQ-1066/sar.r.54043.txt",header=TRUE)
> t2 <- read.table("~/SEQ-1066/sar.q.54043.txt",header=TRUE)
> t1$pt <- strptime(paste(t1$time, t1$AM),"%I:%M:%S %p")
> t2$pt <- strptime(paste(t2$time, t2$AM),"%I:%M:%S %p")
> t <- merge(x=t1,y=t2,by="pt")
Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Thank you R for having such easy to understand error messages.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the datatype of `strptime` is not sortable or usable as a join index, so casting that using `as.POSIXct` worked.

```
t1 <- read.table("~/SEQ-1066/sar.r.54043.txt",header=TRUE)
t2 <- read.table("~/SEQ-1066/sar.q.54043.txt",header=TRUE)
t1$pt <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(t1$time, t1$AM),"%I:%M:%S %p"), tz = "GMT")  
t2$pt <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(t2$time, t2$AM),"%I:%M:%S %p"), tz = "GMT")  
t <- merge(x=t1,y=t2,by="pt")
```

Actual solution was found [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Can-t-merge-on-datetime-td3165187.html), thank you Henrique Dallazuanna.

Comment: To sortof see why have a look at the results from `strptime`: it is a POSIXlt vector : `d = strptime("02/27/92 23:03:20", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S") ; str(d) ; attributes(d)`, so it has many attributes, and this class is known to not play well with dataframes